# Creating apk file with netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans, cordova

I know how to create .apk application with eclipse, but right now I have written it with netbeans and I don't know how to do it.

https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/procedure_for_android_development_on
here is said to click right mouse button on my project and choose "Export Signed Android Package" but I don't have such option.

Answer (score 0):

Try [phonegap cloud build service](https://build.phonegap.com/people/sign_up), it is very good option,  you have to remember to generate your app's config.xml before building online. You can build apk,ipa,oct, etc as you wish.I think you have to install some plugins for build using netbeans.Check for plugin as shown:

Tools-->plugins-->Available plugins

Answer (score 0):

Nativly this is not possible with netbeans. However you can build your project simply my command-line:

```
 phonegap run android
```

However this depends on your platform and your phonegap version, read on: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface